# Convert short to int

Tags: c#

I need to convert a short from the packet header to an integer, what would be the way without affecting its value? Is there anything else I can do?

```
private async void ParsePackets(StreamSocket socket)
{
    using (IInputStream input = socket.InputStream)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[BufferSize];
        IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
        uint dataRead = BufferSize;

        // Wait for payload size
        while (data.Length < 4)
        {
            await input.ReadAsync(buffer, BufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
            dataRead = buffer.Length;

            short payloadSizeShort = 0;
            // Cannot convert from short to system array
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 2, payloadSizeShort, 0, 2);

            int payloadSize = (int)payloadSizeShort;

            // Wait for full message
            while (data.Length < (PacketHeaderSize + payloadSize))
            {
                // Block copy
                // Delete message bytes from buffer
                // Break
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You're already converting it. What more do you want it to do?

Comment: Exactly what do you need to convert? It seems that you copy two bytes into one of two shorts in an array, which you then try to convert to an int?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel It says cannot convert from short[] to int

Comment: So you want to translate two `short`s into a single `int`?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It's just one used for the payload size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just

```
int myInt = (int)BitConverter.ToInt16(data, 2);
```

?

Comment: Packet payload size is on the third byte and it ends on the fourth.

Comment: Yes, offset 2 means 3rd byte. C# arrays are 0-indexed.

Comment: No, it will read from data byte array, from offset 2, where your payload size is. Give it a try.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted that comment already, it reads 2 bytes as you said.

Comment: Btw, you could have stayed to short, without the cast. If you only needed to add it to an integer, .NET knows how to add a short to an integer.

Answer (score 4):

Simply do `(int)shortValue`, you won't lose any information since you convert a 16 bit value to a 32 bit.

Edit: Also, if you have two shorts and you want to make an int out of it, do this:

```
short s0, s1;
int value = s0 << 16 | s1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to cast a short[] to an int. You can cast an individual short to an int by doing (int)myShort, but you can't do that with an array. You have to cast each index individually.

```
short[] myShorts = new short[2];
int[] myInts = new int[myShorts.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < myShorts.Length; i++) {
    myInts[i] = (int)myShorts[i];
}
```

Comment: I've messed up, it's just one short. short payloadSizeShort = new short() should be way to initialize the short but it says i can't be converted to a System.Array.

Comment: That's not how you initialize primitive types, you have to assign it to null or an actual short value. You can do short myShort = 2, then do int myInt = (int)myShort @MiguelRipoll

Comment: What about System.Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 2, payloadSizeShort, 0, 2)? It says that it can't  be converted from short to a System.Array. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you change it so it isn't an array anymore? @MiguelRipoll

Comment: Yes, short payloadSizeShort = 0

Comment: If you read about it here you can see that it only copies from array to array:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx @MiguelRipoll

Answer (score 1):

To get the short from those two bytes in the data you can use the `BitConverter.GetInt16` method.

As converting from `short` to `int` is a widening conversion, you don't even have to specify it, just put the `short` value in an `int` variable and it's implicitly converted:

```
int payloadSize = BitConverter.GetInt16(data, 2);
```